# Iterating with conditions over Distinct Values in a Column

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, for-loop

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

| category | value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | x |
| A | 0.5 | y |
| A | 0.33 | y |
| B | 0.5 | z |
| B | 0.33 | z |
| C | 5 | w |
| C | 0.33 | w |

For each category, I want to grab all the instances that have a value of <= 0.5. I want to have a count of those instances for each category.

My ideal end goal would be to have a dataframe or list with the counts for each of these categories.

Thanks so much for your help.

EDIT:

To get more complex, let's say I want the count for each category where value is <=0.5 but only count each ID once.

Whereas before the values would be:
cat A -> 2, cat B -> 2, cat C -> 1

Now ideal values would be:
Cat A -> 1, cat B -> 1, cat C -> 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on the boolean Series of the comparison of value to 0.5:

```
out = df['value'].le(0.5).groupby(df['category']).sum()
```

Alternatively, use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.loc[df['value'].le(0.5), 'category'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
category
A    2
B    2
C    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I want to get a more complex with it - let's say there's a third column called 'ID'. I want to do the same thing but instead want distinct count based on the ID from new column. How would I go about that?

Comment: depends on the exact logic, can you give an example in the question?

Comment: I added an edit to try to better help what I mean.